# Cannot load Rails due to Switch to inspect mode error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, consul

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. RVM 1.26.11 is installed with Ruby ruby 2.2.0p0. I'm using [envconsul](https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul) to handle environment variables. However, when I do:

`envconsul -config=/etc/envconsul.hcl bundle exec rails c`

it returns this error:

`I, [2015-09-02T00:10:00.420551 #3953]  INFO -- : ** [Raven] Raven 0.14.0 ready to catch errors
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.3)
Switch to inspect mode.`

and just dumps out to the command line. I can run `bundle exec rails c` on its own, but it fails out because the environment variables aren't set. I tried setting an `~/.irbrc` but that doesn't help at all.

I'm really stumped on this one. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
export $(envconsul -consul your_consul_server/agent -prefix your_app_env/ -upcase -pristine -once env)
```

and then:

```
ruby -S bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rails c
```

you can obviously include all these envconsul options in your *.hcl file.